# How to add entries starting from right axis (right to left ) in PhilJay/MPAndroidChart, instead of left

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm creating a line chart where I have to add entries from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the mentioned issues in the library. But the simplest way you can do is by reversing the order of your entries.

If you want axis inverted you can try something like this - https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/2715 . Simply use `set inverted` method.

Comment: what if there if only one entry?